# react TypeScript Error: Types of parameters '__0' and 'props' are incompatible

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am writing a react component which receives an object of the form:

```
accept={{ 1: Component1, 2: Component2}}
```

where the key is a string and the value is a react component. I want to force the component to have a certain prop, "onClick" and all the others are optional/unknown.
this is what i got:

```
export interface IAccept {
  [key: string]: FunctionComponent<IAcceptComponentProps>;
}
export interface IAcceptComponentProps{
  onClick: () => void;
  [key: string]:any
}
```

in the code itself:

```
<Container
  accept={{ test1: TestComponent, test2: TestComponent2 }}
>
```

and the TestComponent signature is:

```
const TestComponent= ({ name, onClick}) =>
```

and i get the following error:
TS2322: Type '({ name, onClick}: { name: any; onClick: any; }) => Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent'.   Types of parameters '__0' and 'props' are incompatible.     Property 'name' is missing in type 'PropsWithChildren' but required in type '{ name: any; onClick: any; }'.

why does typescript require the type definition to have property 'name', i don't want to force it on all the components and i thought '[key: string]:any' would cover that, and how do i fix it?

Comment: Please share the signature (at minimum) of your `Container` component.

Comment: hey ,the container just accepts one prop, the accept prop:
export interface IContainerProps{
  accept:IAccept
}

Comment: The error doesn't say you need to include 'name'. It says 'name' is included in your TestComponent props, which is incompatible with FunctionComponent<IAcceptComponentProps>

Comment: @Burak that's right, but why doesn't '[key: string]:any' cover this case?
in other words, how do i force the TestComponent  to have an onClick prop , and whatever other props it wants?

Comment: @NOCSM Can edit your question to show the *specific* signature of your `Container` component rather than adding a description of it in the comments? Thanks.